# xepersian & polyglossia: section numbering is rtl, even though german is main language

Tags: polyglossia, xepersian, persian, multilingual

I have a document with Persian elements. To get them typeset properly, I am using `xepersian`. Unfortunately, this results in all subsections being numbered RTL instead of LTR, thus 1.2.3 instead of 3.2.1.

[image: what I get]

How can I change this?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% Font and Language Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}          % For font customization
\usepackage{xunicode}          % Extra Unicode support
\usepackage{polyglossia}       % Multilingual support
\usepackage{xepersian}         % Persian (Farsi) support

% Define the Persian (Farsi) font
\newfontfamily\persianfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

% Set Document Languages
\setmainlanguage{german}        % Main document language
\setotherlanguages{persian, english} % Other languages used in the document

\begin{document}

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents

% Sections and Subsections
\section{Einleitung} % German section
This is the introduction section.

\section{Pahlavi-Zukunftsvisionen} % German section
This is the Pahlavi-Zukunftsvisionen section.

\section{Exil-Zukunfts-Vergangenheits-Träumereien} % German section
A section containing subsections.

\subsection{QQ Bang Bang} % German subsection
This is the QQ Bang Bang subsection.

\subsubsection{Erinnerungen und Nostalgie} % German sub-subsection
This is the Erinnerungen und Nostalgie sub-subsection.

\subsection{Another Subsection} % German subsection
This is another subsection.

% Persian Text
\begin{persian}
این یک پاراگراف متن نمونه به زبان فارسی است. % A paragraph of Persian (Farsi) text.

این یک مثال از یک شعر به زبان فارسی است: % An example of a Persian (Farsi) poem.
\end{persian}

% English Text
\begin{english}
This is a paragraph of dummy text in English. % A paragraph of English text.
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you have only a few persian elements xepersian is probably not suited. It (and bidi too) changes a lot of things. Consider to use lualatex + babel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xepersian` package is mostly useful when your main text is going to be in Farsi, otherwise you have to configure a lot of things to use it effectively. Instead, I suggest using the `bidi` package, assuming you will only have a small number of sentences in Farsi.

Here I defined a new command `\persiantext` that sets the text direction to right-to-left and uses the correct font for that part. You just need to use this when you have some text in Farsi.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

% Font and Language Packages
\usepackage{fontspec}          % For font customization
\usepackage{xunicode}          % Extra Unicode support
\usepackage{polyglossia}       % Multilingual support
\usepackage{bidi}              % For RTL support

% Define the Persian (Farsi) font
\newfontfamily{\persianfont}[Script=Arabic]{Vazirmatn}

% Set Document Languages
\setmainlanguage{german}        % Main document language
\setotherlanguages{persian,english} % Other languages used in the document

% Command to set the text direction and font for Persian text
\newcommand{\persiantext}[1]{\begin{RTL} {\persianfont #1} \end{RTL}}

\begin{document}

% Table of Contents
\tableofcontents

% Sections and Subsections
\section{Einleitung} % German section
This is the introduction section.

\section{Pahlavi-Zukunftsvisionen} % German section
This is the Pahlavi-Zukunftsvisionen section.

\section{Exil-Zukunfts-Vergangenheits-Träumereien} % German section
A section containing subsections.

\subsection{QQ Bang Bang} % German subsection
This is the QQ Bang Bang subsection.

\subsubsection{Erinnerungen und Nostalgie} % German sub-subsection
This is the Erinnerungen und Nostalgie sub-subsection.

\subsection{Another Subsection} % German subsection
This is another subsection.

% Persian Text
\persiantext{
این یک پاراگراف متن نمونه به زبان فارسی است. % A paragraph of Persian (Farsi) text.

این یک مثال از یک شعر به زبان فارسی است: % An example of a Persian (Farsi) poem.
}

% English Text
\begin{english}
This is a paragraph of dummy text in English. % A paragraph of English text.
\end{english}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I also have a longer sections of 2-3 pages in Persian thought, typeset in the `verse` environment. At the moment, I use `polyglossia`'s `\begin{persian} ... \end{persian}`. I probably can't replace that with this solution, right? I cannot find proper documentation for `bidi`'s `modernpoem` environment, otherwise I would happily use that!

Comment: Having longer text might make things a bit difficult but as long as the whole thing is just a few paragraphs of text with nothing fancy then I think the above solution should work fine. Did you run into any issues?

Regarding `bidi`, here is the official documentation: https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/xetex/latex/bidi/bidi-doc.pdf